# Method signature arguments of type(self)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods, method-signature

When I define a class, how can I include arguments in its methods' signatures which have to be of the same class? I am building a graph structure which should work like this, but here is a simplified example:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, value: int, previous: Dummy=None):
        self._value = value
        self._previous = previous

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def plus_previous(self):
        return self.value + self._previous.value

d1 = Dummy(7)
d2 = Dummy(3, d1)
d2.plus_previous()
```

This results in the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Dummy' is not defined
```

I mean, I can do it the Python 2 way, but I was hoping there is a more python-3-ic solution than this:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, value: int, previous=None):
        assert type(previous) is Dummy or previous is None
        ...
```

Comment: PS: obviously, I can't use:

    type(self)

as self is not defined yet in the signature. I could only do this:

    assert type(previous) is type(self)

which at least is a small improvement

Comment: As an aside, you realize that type hints will not work like the `assert` statement, right? They aren't enforced. They are *hints*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I agree, it is a rather *ugly* hack, you can use strings as type hints as well:

```
class Dummy:
    def __init__(self, value: int, previous: 'Dummy'=None):
        self._value = value
        self._previous = previous

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def plus_previous(self):
        return self.value + self._previous.value
```

as is described in [**PEP-484**](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) on type hints:

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that
>   definition may be expressed **as a string literal, to be resolved later**.
>
> A situation where this occurs commonly is the definition of a
>   container class, where the class being defined occurs in the signature
>   of some of the methods. For example, the following code (the start of
>   a simple binary tree implementation) does not work:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> To address this, we write:
>
> ```
> class Tree:
>     def __init__(self, left: 'Tree', right: 'Tree'):
>         self.left = left
>         self.right = right
> ```
>
> The **string literal should contain a valid Python expression** (i.e.,
>   `compile(lit, '', 'eval')` should be a valid code object) and it should
>   evaluate without errors once the module has been fully loaded. The
>   local and global namespace in which it is evaluated should be the same
>   namespaces in which default arguments to the same function would be
>   evaluated.

A problem with this hack however is that if you do a **rename in the IDE**, it is definitely possible that the IDE will not take these string literals into account and thus fail to rename these.